# Optimizing Django queries in nested loops

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, optimization, django-queryset

I'm developing a Django application that helps analyze radio signal propogations from transmitters in various locations. The raw data is obtained from a MySQL database that keeps a record of each signal received by a reporter and its origin and timestamp.

The idea is to check for the status of a receiver relative to a target transmitter during a particular time interval/block. The filtered results needs to be returned as a JSON file.

```
# All records within the time frame in question
qs_spots = Spot.objects.filter(unix_time__range = (starttime, endtime))
qs_spots = qs_spots_all.values()

# the focus is on a particular transmitter tx
tx_dict = {}
tx_dict['tx_callsign'] = tx

interval_range = 120

# list of all unique receivers - the field is called 'reporter' in the model
rx_list = qs_spots.values_list('reporter', flat=True).distinct()
tx_dict['rx_total'] = len(rx_list)
tx_dict['receivers'] = []

# goes through each reporter in the list
for rx in rx_list:
    rx_dict = {}
    rx_dict['rx_callsign'] = rx

    rx_spots = qs_spots.filter(reporter=rx)

    rx_dict['time_state'] = []

    current_time = starttime
    while current_time <= endtime:
        next_time = current_time + interval_range # increment next time interval
        time_dict = {}
        time_dict['datetime'] = current_time

        rx_time = rx_spots.filter(unix_time__range = (current_time, next_time))
        # first check if any records exist for the particular interval
        if rx_time.exists():                        
            # then check the transmitter status
            if rx_time.filter(transmitter=tx).exists():
                time_dict['status'] = 0 # reporter is receiving from target transmitter
            else:
                time_dict['status'] = 1 # reporter is not receiving from target transmitter, but is receiving from other transmitters
        else:
            # if no records exists for the particular interval
            # i.e reporter is not receiving at all during this interval
            time_dict['status'] = 2

        current_time = next_time # set to next interval

        rx_dict['time_state'].append(time_dict.copy())  

    tx_dict['receivers'].append(rx_dict.copy())

response = json.dumps(tx_dict, cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
return HttpResponse(response, content_type='application/json')
```

I tested the outer loop by itself and it works fine, albeit slow - returning a JSON list of 50-100 receivers anywhere between 30 seconds to 2 minutes. The problem comes when I add the inner loop to check the status of the target transmitter. The results never returns, even after hours.

I've tried it with various time ranges, but my "default" is about 50 receivers in a 1 hour window in intervals of 120 seconds (2 mins). 50*(60/2) = 1500 loops in total. Doesn't sound like a lot for a computer to crunch through, but something is causing it to lock up.

**EDIT:** Added my models.py if it helps

```
class Spot(models.Model):
    spot_id = models.IntegerField(db_column='Spot_ID', primary_key=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    unix_time = models.IntegerField(db_column='UNIX_time', blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    reporter = models.CharField(db_column='Reporter', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.
    transmitter = models.CharField(db_column='Transmitter', max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)  # Field name made lowercase.

class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'SPOT'
```

**EDIT 2:**
Tried converting the querysets to dictionaries and limiting the fields

```
qs_spots = qs_spots.values('unix_time', 'reporter', 'transmitter')

rx_spots = qs_spots.filter(reporter=rx).values('unix_time', 'reporter', 'transmitter')

rx_time = rx_spots.filter(unix_time__range = (current_time, next_time)).values('transmitter')
```

The outer loop *seems* to run faster, but the inner loop still gets locked up.

Sample expected JSON response

```
{
  "tx_callsign": "EA4DUT",
  "rx_total": 3,
  "receivers": [
    {
      "rx_callsign": "G1RWT"
      "time_state": [
        { "datetime": 1443963600, "status": 0 },
        { "datetime": 1443963720, "status": 1 },
        { "datetime": 1443963840, "status": 2 }
        ]
    },
    {
      "rx_callsign": "PI4THT"
      "time_state": [
        { "datetime": 1443963600, "status": 1 },
        { "datetime": 1443963720, "status": 0 },
        { "datetime": 1443963840, "status": 2 }
        ]
    },
    {
      "rx_callsign": "EI6KD"
      "time_state": [
        { "datetime": 1443963600, "status": 2 },
        { "datetime": 1443963720, "status": 0 },
        { "datetime": 1443963840, "status": 0 }
        ]
    },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Well if you want better performance I would suggest dig more into django queryset, as general rule of the thumb is that your database will be quicker in filtering data then raw python.

Comment: Do you mean to try with Django's RawSQL, instead of using filters?

Comment: RawSQL should be your last resort, try to be more specific on your filters, `rx_time = rx_spots.filter(unix_time__range = (current_time, next_time), unix_time__isnull = False)` this should remove the .exist() method. Also I would suggest to rethink your model a little bit, so it has foreign key to it's receivers and the instead of using json.dump use [django serializers link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/serialization/)

Comment: Try adding a receiver field to spot which is foreignkey to spot, and create new model for timestate, so that spot has relationship to that as well (think of it that you need to remove all the relationship data from your python and store it in database)

Comment: that would be an option if I had full control over the raw data that is generated. Currently the data is obtained from an external source in CSV format, and all I'm doing is porting it over into a MySQL db. I have no way to enforce foreign key restrictions without risking data from brand new receivers/transmitters being omitted.There are probably ways around it - like updating the "callsign" table with new callsigns first before loading in the new data, but I'm looking if there's any other way before I go to that, because it would mean additional overhead in maintaining multiple tables.